# table name in loop oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 declare
     v_cnt        NUMBER;
     C SYS_REFCURSOR;
 TMP_TBL_NM VARCHAR2(100);
     stmt VARCHAR2(1000); 
     the_name varchar2 (50);
          cursor c_table is
            (SELECT a.table_name 
            --, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner,            
           --c.r_owner       , c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
      FROM all_cons_columns a
      JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
      JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
     WHERE c.owner like '%LTR' and c_pk.table_name like '%EnumerationValue%');    
      begin
      stmt := 'SELECT table_name  FROM ' || TMP_TBL_NM || ' ORDER BY 1';
        OPEN C FOR stmt;
        for t in C
          loop
          FETCH C INTO the_name;
          EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
          --my query for each table goes here
         end loop;
     end;
```

i want to use table names in loop as to check the records as per my query.
it is giving me error only by getting table name in the loop.
how can i get table name in a loop so that i can fetch rows as per my requirement from each table in a loop.

thanks in advance.

Comment: TMP_TBL_NM is not defined anywhere, apparently

Comment: edited.. still getting the error

Comment: *getting error* is not an acceptable standard Oracle error. Show us the error.

Comment: ORA-06550: line 18, column 18:
PLS-00221: 'C' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 18, column 9:

Comment: TMP_TBL_NM is not getting assigned a value anywhere, apparently

Comment: @ammoQ its been declared.. see the edited version please

Comment: it is declared, but did you also give it a value?

Comment: i want to select rows from each table coming from the constraints query, please tell me how to do it. thank you. the above you are watching is my try so far.

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli ErikL's answer shows you how to get the table names; for the "selecting rows for each query" part, well, you can do it using e.g. DBMS_SQL, but for what purpose? How do you plan to process a mixed bag of rows from different tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve here, but if it's just the table names you're interested in, you can make your code a lot less complicated doing it this way:

```
declare
     cursor c_table is
            SELECT a.table_name 
            --, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner,            
           --c.r_owner       , c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
      FROM all_cons_columns a
      JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
      JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
begin
    for t in c_table loop
        --do something with the table name
        dbms_output.put_line(t.table_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

This kind of for loop also handles the opening and closing of the cursor and is the recommended way to do these kind of operations.